# I defined a random number and i want to check if it is a palindrome java

Tags: java, palindrome

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Loop6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random number = new Random();
        int value = number.nextInt(1000);
        System.out.println("random number : " + " " + value);

        int rev = 0;
        int dig;

        while (value > 0) {
            dig = value % 10;
            rev = rev * 10;
            rev = rev + dig;
            value = value / 10;
        }
        System.out.println("rev is : " + "" + rev);
        if(value==rev) {
            System.out.println("Palindrome");

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Store the value of `value` in a temp variable and then compare temp variable with `rev`.

Comment: do not change value,take another variable initialize with value and do calculation on that variable.

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is almost fine, it's just you're updating the initial random number which is not what you want. To keep changes to the code at minimal, I propose you to add a new variable and compare it to the result of your reverse algorithm.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Loop6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random number = new Random();
        int randomNumber = number.nextInt(1000);  // introduce the initial variable
        int value = randomNumber;  // introduce the variable that will be updated
        System.out.println("random number : " + " " + value);

        int rev = 0;
        int dig;

        while (value > 0) {
            dig = value % 10;
            rev = rev * 10;
            rev = rev + dig;
            value = value / 10;
        }
        System.out.println("rev is : " + "" + rev);
        if (randomNumber == rev) {  // compare the initial variable and the reverse result
            System.out.println("Palindrome");

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java has built-in methods to reverse the strings.

```
String originalValue = value + "";
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(originalValue);
String reverseValue = stringBuilder.reverse().toString();

if (originalValue.equals(reverseValue)) System.out.println("Palindrome");
```

Comment: You can do `if((value+"").equals(new StringBuilder().append(value).reverse().toString())` +1

Comment: agreed, but having in mind Java expertise of the author(strictly IMHO), I wanted a more readable solution.

Comment: agreed, which is why I commented on your answer to you instead of posting it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random number = new Random();
        int value = number.nextInt(1000);
        System.out.println("Original number : " + " " + value);
        int tmp = value;
        int result = 0;
        while (tmp != 0) {
            result = result * 10 + (tmp % 10);
            tmp = tmp / 10;
        }
        System.out.println("Reversed Number : " + " " + result);
        if (result != value) {
            System.out.println("Not Palindrome");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Palindrome");
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks :)